# Weird shadow bug when using mask

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, mask

Do you know how to get rid of that weird shadow behaviour? Shadow should **not** show circle's line. Circle line should be only inside rectangle

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.yellow)
                .cornerRadius(25)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 700)
                .padding(.leading, 30)
                .padding(.trailing, 30)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 12, x: 0, y: 4)

            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .opacity(0.2)
                .cornerRadius(25)
                .frame(width: 1300, height: 1300)
                .mask (
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.backgroundColor)
                        .offset(x: 80, y: -900)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not weird, you applied shadow to one rect, but mask to another (much wider), and 2nd, which is transparent placed over the first, so of course due to transparency entire below content is visible through above. It shows exactly what you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, make your View more "generic"

```
struct MyView: View {
    let relativeRadius: CGFloat
    let unitPoint: UnitPoint
    let color: Color
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat
    let shadowRadius: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxyOuter in
            Rectangle().fill(self.color)
        .overlay(
            GeometryReader { proxy in
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.primary.opacity(0.2))
                .colorInvert().offset(x: proxy.size.width * self.unitPoint.x, y: -proxy.size.height * self.unitPoint.y)
                .frame(width: proxy.size.width * self.relativeRadius, height: proxy.size.height * self.relativeRadius)
            }
        )
            .frame(width: proxyOuter.size.width, height: proxyOuter.size.height)
            // mask is redundant if using .cornerRadius, which is "mask" as well 
            .mask(Color.primary)
                .cornerRadius(self.cornerRadius)
                // see more parameters for shadow
                // i like :-)
                // .shadow(color: Color.secondary, radius: self.shadowRadius, x: self.shadowRadius, y: self.shadowRadius)
                .shadow(radius: self.shadowRadius)
        }
    }
}
```

and next use it the "standard way"

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView(relativeRadius: 1.5, unitPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.2, y: 0.75), color: Color.yellow, cornerRadius: 30, shadowRadius: 10)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
            // to see the bounding box (used for stacking), uncomment next line
            //.border(Color.red)
    }
}
```

and here you can see the result

[image]